# retornar select "tabela relacionada" no laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, formulário, modal

Olá minha aplicação foi desenvolvida em laravel e como complemento estou usando alguns componentes do VueJS.

Vamos ao problema, tenho uma tabela cliente fazendo relacionamento com país.
Na mesma view index.blade de clientes eu abro uma modal para criar, editar e visualizar o cliente.
A questão é que para criar o cliente ele apresenta o select com os países cadastrados, porém ao editar ou visualizar ele não retorna os países. Vamos ao código:

ClientesController: (Nele eu chamo tb o model pais)

```
public function index()
{
    $listaClientes = Cliente::select('id', 'nome', 'tva', 'pais_id', 'cp', 'cidade', 'endereco')->paginate(10);

    $pais = Pais::all();

    return view('app.clientes.index',compact('listaClientes', 'pais'));
}
```

Model Pais:

```
{
use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'paises';
protected $fillable = ['id', 'nome'];

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Model cliente:

```
use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'clientes';
protected $fillable = ['nome', 'tva','pais_id', 'cp', 'cidade', 'endereco'];

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function pais() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pais', 'pais_id', 'nome');
```

Select do modal adicionar:

```
<select name="pais_id" class="form-control">
   @foreach ($pais as $pais)
      <option value="{{ $pais->id }}">{{ $pais->nome }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Select do modal editar:

```
<select name="pais_id" class="form-control">
   @foreach ($pais as $pais)
      <option value="{{ $pais->id }}">{{ $pais->nome }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Meus formulários de adição e edição estão no mesmo arquivo blade e abre a modal...

Desde já agradeço por sua atenção, se tiver algo mais que eu precise enviar...

Comment: Posta a saida de dump($pais); ou dd($pais);
Dica, muda  $pais = Pais::all(); pra  $paises = Pais::all(); para que no foreach não fique tão confuso :)

Comment: Opa, obrigado Marcos.
Eu consegui aqui com a ajuda de um outro rapaz, exatamente como você indicou.
Valeuuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em ambos os `foreach`, você utilizou o nome do item igual o nome da collection `$pais => $pais`, isso é uma possível fonte do bug. Para corrigir isso sugiro que no controller, substitua a variável `$pais` por `$paises`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public function index()
{
    $listaClientes = Cliente::select('id', 'nome', 'tva', 'pais_id', 'cp', 'cidade', 'endereco')->paginate(10);

    $paises = Pais::all();

    return view('app.clientes.index',compact('listaClientes', 'paises'));
}
```

E na view, altere `@foreach($pais as $pais)` por `@foreach($paises as $pais)`